# How often is 2 a principal root of unity modulo a prime $p$?

Tags: prime-numbers, intuition, roots-of-unity

We know, from [Bertand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) that there is always a prime number between $n$ and $2n$, for $n > 3$.  I'm wondering if there is a similar conjecture for the number $2$ being a principal root of unity modulo a prime $p$, with maximum multiplicative order.

To make this more clear, I'm wondering if we can say something like $2$ is a principal root of unity, with maximum multiplicative order, modulo some prime $p$, with $n \le p \le \alpha \cdot n$, for all $n$ and some constant $\alpha$ that is preferably small.  Does this $\alpha << \infty$ exist?

Comment: What do you mean a "principal root of unity modulo a prime $p$"?  Did you mean a primitive root?

Comment: @lulu:  Sorry, thinking about things, I may need $2$ to be both, if that is possible.  I'm really looking for a principal root of unity that also has maximum multiplicative order, if it's possible.

Comment: Well, I don't understand what the first condition is. if $k$ is the order of $2\pmod p$ then isn't $2$ a primitive $k^{th}$ root of unity $\pmod p$?

Comment: @lulu:  I'm looking for how often it occurs that $k=(p-1)$.  Additionally, $2$ must be a principal root of unity.

Comment: That condition is just called being a primitive root. It is a wide open problem whether there are even infinitely many primes $p$ for which this is true.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan:  That's what I was afraid of.  I wonder if there are any conditional results, such as assuming the generalized Riemann hypothesis.  Is there any situation in which $2$ or, really, any constant integer such as $100000$ occurs in this way?

Comment: As I say, I don't understand what the "principal" condition means in this context.  I think you are just looking for a primitive root.  And, as others have remarked, it's unknown whether there are infinitely many such $p$.

Comment: @lulu:  Just to be brief:  According to Wikipedia, the primitive roots are always principal roots (of unity) in an integral domain, and I know that I need a principal root, so I believe now that we are ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Artin's conjecture on primitive roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots), there are infinitely many primes for
which $2$ is a primitive root, and the asymptotic density of these in the primes is
Artin's constant, approximately 0.3739558136.  However,
 the conjecture is still open.

See also [OEIS sequence A001122](https://oeis.org/A001122).

Comment: I see that Pieter Moree writes that assuming GRH, it is essentially proven.  Anyways thanks for adding the OEIS entry, and of course thanks for the answer.